# How can I add time field in incoming messages?

Tags: c, contiki

I am looking for a way to add time field in incoming message, either of seconds or milliseconds so that I can calculate the amount of time taken in reception of a packet, for determining the latency, in Contiki. I am currently using TI cc2650 board

Comment: What do you mean by timestamp? Should it be the wall-clock time, or network-wide time, or the uptime of the local node, or something else?

Comment: I want to add some time field either of seconds or milliseconds so that I can calculate the amount of time taken in reception of a packet, for determining the latency. I came across "rtimer_now()" function, but I am not very sure to how to use it to achieve my goal.

Comment: `man clock_gettime`  gives you the system time, or process time, depending which clock you ask for a timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to run a time synchronization protocol such as TSCH to have a common notion of time on both the sender and receiver node.

Contiki-NG has [an example](https://github.com/contiki-ng/contiki-ng/tree/develop/examples/6tisch/timesync-demo) in `examples/6tisch/timesync-demo` that shows how to use TSCH to calculate the latency. The output of `tsch_get_network_uptime_ticks()` is in clock ticks, but you can convert from ticks to seconds by dividing the value in ticks with `CLOCK_SECOND`, which a configuration-specific constant.